# Android string-array to Array

Tags: android, arrays

This time I want to get an array-list element from strings.xml and convert it to an array (String[], List or whatever can later be used to read the elements or the total size). I am trying with `List<String> MathFormulas = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.id.StringArray));` but the application crashes, so this must be the wrong way of doing it. Some help? Thanks!

Comment: 04-23 17:10:30.101: E/AndroidRuntime(1516): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f08000f

Comment: Please add an update to your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see that you are using identifier R.**id**.StringArray when it should start with R.**array**. The rest of the code looks OK to me.

Comment: It was that. I am staying in front of this stupid plastic box since this morning. I am loosing my minds. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

you can convert it to string arrar as below::

```
String[] cmd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.StringArray);
```

or

```
List<String> MathFormulas = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.StringArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try R.array.StringArray instead of R.id.StringArray.